# unable to inline partially applied function with andThen

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

Here are two example functions

```
def fun1(s: String, x: Int) = x
def fun2(x: Int) = x
```

I would like to partially apply `fun1` and compose it with `fun2` using `andThen`.

Here is what I would like to say

```
fun1("", _: Int) andThen fun2 _
```

But I get

```
<console>:14: error: value andThen is not a member of Int
       fun1("", _: Int) andThen fun2 _
```

The following code works

```
val a = fun1("", _: Int)
a andThen fun2 _
```

or even

```
((fun1("", _: Int)): Int => Int) andThen fun2 _
```

`fun1("", _: Int)` is not seen as function without help. Why is that? I cannot understand how does compiler reason about types in this case. Here is even more wired example

```
def fun1(s: String, x: Int) = s
def fun2(s: String) = s

fun1(_: String, 1) andThen fun2 _

<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => String
 required: Char => ?
       fun1(_: String, 1) andThen fun2 _
```

Where does `Char` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for [Placeholder Syntax for Anonymous Functions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions) imply that
`fun1("", _: Int) andThen fun2 _` means `x: Int => fun1("", x) andThen fun2 _`. `fun1("", x)` has type `Int`, and doesn't have `andThen`, as the compiler tells you. What you want is `{ x: Int => fun1("", x) } andThen fun2 _` instead (`(fun1("", _: Int)) andThen fun2 _` also works, but I don't think it's readable).